# jQuery adding elements to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to add elements to a parent object on a click event.

The result that i'm hoping to achieve is this:

```
<ul>
        <li><button>B1</button>
            <ul class="newul">
                <li><button>B1.1</button>
                    <ul class="newul">
                        <li><button>1.1.1</button></li>
                        <li><button>1.1.2</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><button>B1.1</button></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><button>B2</button></li>
        <li><button>B3</button></li>
</ul>
```

Let's say I click button B2. I want a new UL added to the parent LI of that button and then be able to add new LI elements to the newly created UL. I hope that makes sense!

So basically, click button, add new UL with class "newul" to the LI you're currently in -> add new LI's to that newly created UL.

The jquery I'm currently using is as follows:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    //Get parent..
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        //Add a new UL to the parent and save it as newul           
        var newul = parent.add("ul");
                    //Add the class to the new UL
        newul.addClass('newul');               
        //Add a new li to the new UL            
            newli = newul.add('li');
            //Add a button to the new LI
            newli.append('<button></button>');

});
```

Unfortunately, this is having completely undesired effects and sticks buttons everywhere all over the place. I'd appreciate any help you can offer.

Here's a visible example of what i'm after. The top part is the effect id like to achieve.

[Example of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsxy4.jpg)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even though [@am not i am has the correct code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11248975/570918).  There is no explanation of why your code fails, and I think that's the answer you are asking for.

There are several problems in your code:

First

```
//Add a new UL to the parent and save it as newul           
var newul = parent.add("ul");
```

The `'ul'` is a selector and so is going to search the DOM for other `<ul>` elements, rather than create a new one.  Also, `parent.add()` method is returning the `parent` object, not the ul's that you selected.

Correct code:

```
//Add a new UL to the parent and save it as newul           
var newul = $("<ul>").appendTo(parent);
```

Second:

```
//Add a new li to the new UL            
newli = newul.add('li');
```

Same problem again, and since `newul` is actually still the `parent` you're getting all types of craziness.  Also, you're missing a `var`, but maybe I just don't get your closure.

Correct code:

```
//Add a new li to the new UL         
var newli = $("<li>").appendTo(newul);
```

That's all.  If you fix that in your code, it'll work.

However, unless you really need those references to persist, better performance is usually achieved if you pass the whole thing as a string:

```
$('button').click( function() {

  $(this).parent()
    .append(
      $('<ul class="newul"><li><button></li></ul>')
    );
});
```

### Edit

And if you wanted all the new buttons to have the same functionality, use the [`on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and a class for your buttons:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.ul-appending', function() {

  $(this).parent()
    .append(
      $('<ul class="newul"><li><button class="ul-appending"></li></ul>')
    );
});
```

You could change the `'body'` selector to something much more specific so this doesn't get queried on every click on your page.  Just make sure to add the class `ul-appending` to all the existing buttons that aren't generated by this handler.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3em3B/3/)

Comment: Also, [as @JohnKalberer points out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11249182/570918), this will not add this click event to the buttons you're creating.  But I don't think that's you're question here.

Comment: Yeah. What would I have to edit if I wanted each sequentially added button to respond to the click event too?

Comment: @user1489130 I'll add it to my answer explicitly, but you should make sure to +1 [@JohnKalberer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11249182/570918), since it pointed this out.

Comment: @merv, I have check you jsfillde, and its working fine upto 100 sub ul li, than after it will not work, I need same output upto nth ul li, can u pls help me for that

Comment: @nim that sounds like a valid standalone question to ask, rather than appending to this one.  Of course, you can always reference this one in the new question.

Answer (score 1):

One issue I see here is that the new buttons created will not have the click event bound to them.  I fix this by using `on` and setting the event as a delegate.  In doing so I give the outer `ul` an `id` of `container`.  I also check to make sure you haven't already added a `ul` element and append one if it isn't inside the `li`.  [Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/3em3B/6/).

```
$('#container').on("click", "button.newbtn", function(){
    var parent = $(this).closest('li');
    var childUl = parent.children('ul');
    if(childUl.length === 0) {
        parent.append("<ul class='newul'></ul>");
        childUl = parent.children('ul');       
    }
    childUl.append($("<li><button class='newbtn'>" + $(this).html() + "." + (childUl.children().length + 1) + "</button></li>"));
});​
```

Comment: I'd also recommend adding a class to the `<button>`, and thence the selector in the `on()` method, just in case there might be other buttons in that `#container` in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function(){
         //Get parent..
        var parent = $(this).parent();

        //Add a new UL to the parent and save it as newul           
        var newul = $("<ul/>");

        //Add the class to the new UL
        newul.addClass('newul');               

        //Add a new li to the new UL            
        var newli = $('<li/>');

        //Add a button to the new LI
        newli.append('<button></button>');

        // add ul to parent li
        parent.append( newul.append( newli ) );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're using [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) instead of [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

`.add()` adds the passed element to the current selection. `.after()` adds the passed elements after the current selection.

Using `.after()`, we can simplify your script into a nice little one-liner:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $(this).after('<ul class="newul"><li><button></button></li></ul>');
});​
```

Since `.after()` inserts content next to the current element, there's no need to get the `.parent()`. `.after()` can take a complete string of HTML, so there's no need to use jQuery to manipulate the class and add the child elements.

**[Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/cpCmy/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function for dynamically added elements.

You can use something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    i = 1;
    $('body').on("click","button",function(event){
        $(this).after('<ul class="newul"><li><button>TestButton'+i+'</button></li></ul>');
        i++;
    });
});
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NQy4a/2/). Adjust button with your css and button values accordingly.

​